# Is it possible to nest docker/podman containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu, fedora, podman

I run Fedora 35, and need to run an app in docker in ubuntu.
I was able to get and run ubuntu via podman

```
podman pull ubuntu:20.04
```

and setup do docker there, but can't make it run as I probably didn't enter podman properly probably. I used:

```
podman run -it ubuntu:20.04
```

where I ran:

```
su -
apt update; apt upgrade
apt install inetutils-ping nano sudo npm
apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \                                                                                            $(lsb_release -cs) stable" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null                                                                                                                                  apt update
apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

to start docker via `systectl` is not possible in the container, and `dockerd` command gives many error, mostly that it can't access overlay, and probably network (iptables)

ERRO[2022-05-07T23:14:18.803335993+02:00] failed to mount overlay: operation not permitted  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2022-05-07T23:14:18.803397023+02:00] exec: "fuse-overlayfs": executable file not found in $PATH  storage-driver=fuse-overlayfs
ERRO[2022-05-07T23:14:18.803500924+02:00] AUFS wdas not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2022-05-07T23:14:18.803887884+02:00] failed to mount overlay: operation not permitted  storage-driver=overlay

Is it possible at all to run and app with service to have open port to outside of docker, and podman as there are 2 layers of nested containers?

Comment: It seems it's even possible to run Run __Podman__ in __Podman__ in __Podman__ https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31058079

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use the default storage driver of type `overlay` inside another container, you need to change the storage to `vfs`. Maybe https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/ helps.

Disclaimer: This works definitely in case of running podman in docker, but the other way around I have not tested.